# IE doesn't run Javascript when you click 'back' button

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer

I've built a shop with tons of JS running.
One of the pieces of the cart, is a zip code field which is required to calculate shipping cost.

This works fine going through the cart. Now clicking checkout takes you to paypal.
If you click back, in IE the setup scripts (like clear the zip field) aren't fired.

They work in Safari & FF, but IE unless you do a refresh, script won't re-check the shipping cost and the user ends up having free shipping.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this?
Thanks
Rich

--- code snippet ----

```
function loadCartTriggers() {
    if($('cart')) {
        var size_menus = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        $('zip').value = '';
        giftOption();
        for(i=0; i<size_menus.length; i++) {
            addEvent('change', updateProdData, size_menus[i].id);
        }
        addEvent('click', giftOption, 'gift');
        addEvent('keyup', getShipRate, 'zip');
        addEvent('click', checkZip, 'checkout_faux');
        addEvent('click', giftCharge, 'gift');
    }
}

loadCartTriggers();
```

bsn . krd . webhop .net / shop

(just didnt want the address indexed)

Comment: How are you firing the setup code?

Comment: I think you should post sample code and/or a URL to a live example. When I built my shopping cart I had a page where the user clicks to pay through paypal. Then I take them to a middle page with all the hidden post data (it can be tampered with, but it is fairly hard and I only do this to keep out the average person. Even if I encrypted the post data, the "hacker" can still change HTML code to put his own hidden variables in there.), then it automatically redirects with the post data to paypal and then they pay.

Comment: The problem isn't so much passing data to PayPal - its more in the event a user clicks back on the browser. In IE (and FF) rather than reloading the page - its cached. But only in IE, the scripts do not fire.

I'll post some snippets since the whole code lengthy.

Comment: do you have a <cart> tag somewhere??

Comment: yep, the cart is there, because this loads fine when you first go to the page, or refresh. I guess ill post the link

Comment: What JS library are you using (the origin of the $ function)?

Answer (score 1):

As a practice, you should **never, ever** rely on client-side (Javascript) form validation because any field that is populated by Javascript can be tampered. I'm assuming you're using the PayPal form checkout. Your options include using PayPal's form encrypting/encoding (this would allow you to submit the ZIP code business).

**No matter what**, though, you should always use PayPal's email notification or IPN to verify all the entries. If you want more help on server-size validation, follow up with a comment, and someone can direct you to the API.